# Reuse Ant build.xml for TFS 2013 BuildDefinitions

Tags: java, ant, tfs, tfsbuild

I have successfully built a Java web application using TFS's java support via ant. My problem is that I have several applications that share a common build process and would like to reuse the build.xml (with parameters passed in to differentiate the output), however, the TFS Build Definition does not allow me to reference a build.xml file that is in a shared location outside of the workspace mapping for my particular build.

For example, assuming the following Version Control structure:

Source
  Applications
      Application 1
        Main
          src
          WebContent
      Application 2
        Main
          src
          WebContent

For each build definition I would like root to be that of the Main branch of that application so that only those source files are copied to the build server. I would like the build.xml to be stored in, say, Applications directory as it will be shared across Application 1 and Application 2. When I try this I get the following error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\BuildExtensions\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Extensions.Ant.targets (306): There is no working folder mapping for $/Source/Applications/build.xml

This is because my Source Control Folder in the build definition is set to a child folder (Main). If I set my Source Control Folder to be the Applications folder, I believe it will work, however, I then notice that the build attempts to transfer ALL files under Applications to the build server which slows the build down to a crawl. Any thoughts on how I can achieve the desired reuse? Perhaps something in the TFSBuild.proj file that would restrict the files that get transferred using a parameter ${ApplicationName}/Main or something like that?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up you workspace to include folders and cloak others. I can imagine that it would be arouse work to cloak all of the other stuff in scope. A recommended practice would be to have the shared folder under its own folder rather than the root of applications. That way you can map that folder explicitly as well as the branch that you want to build.

When the XAML builds are retired at launch of TFS 2015 the new build system allows you to have tasks that are shared between build definitions.

Comment: Just discovered that you could map additional folders and this would work if I moved the build.xml elsewhere. Great solution.